# maven deploy works with snapshots but 404 for releases

Tags: maven, nexus3

I am trying to deploy to our internal nexus repository. I have configured a maven project where I can do a `mvn install` and `mvn clean deploy`. The odd thing is when I remove `SNAPSHOT` from the version, I get a `404`.

Here is my pom.xml that works for `SNAPSHOTS`:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>MavenExample</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.mycompany</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <url>http://nexus.mycompany.com:8000/repository/maven-releases/</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <url>http://nexus.mycompany.com:8000/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <serverId>nexus</serverId>
          <nexusUrl>http://nexus.mycompany.com:8000/repository/maven-releases/</nexusUrl>
          <!-- update this to the correct id! -->
          <stagingProfileId>myid</stagingProfileId>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

When I change `<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>` to `<version>1.0</version>`

I Get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.3:deploy (injected-nexus-deploy) on project explicit-staging-example: Execution injected-nexus-deploy of goal org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.3:deploy failed: Nexus connection problem to URL [http://nexus.mycompany.com:8000/repository/maven-releases/ ]: 404 - Not Found -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

They are both available in nexus:

[image: maven]

I have tried adding different plugins but no luck. I'm not a maven expert so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using the community edition of Nexus? I don't think it supports staging.

Comment: @SteveC Yes we are - OSS 3.3.0-01. This is just temporary.

Comment: Yes, but I don't believe the OSS version supports staging, and you're failing while trying to execute the `nexus-staging-maven-plugin`.

Comment: Gotcha. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: If you get rid of that plugin it should "just work"

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not able to deploy staged releases because you're using the community edition of Nexus right now, and it does not support this functionality.

For now you need to remove the `nexus-staging-maven-plugin` configuration from your pom.xml and the regular

```
mvn clean deploy
```

will "just work" (but without staging).

Answer (score 6):

When I used Steve C's answer, maven just stopped deploying. I instead passed `-DskipStaging=true`, as documented [here](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-maven-plugins/tree/master/staging/maven-plugin#deferred-deploy). This allowed me to keep using the `nexus-staging-maven-plugin`, just without the staging capability.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue and this one works for me.

```
mvn clean install deploy -DskipStaging=true
```